# "UI element states pseudo-class (:checked)" property remains although checkbox already unchecked in mobile environment

Tags: html, css

Thanks for replying kind answers every time.

I am struggling with a problem that "UI element states pseudo-class" does not work normally (as I intended) in the mobile environment.

Here are the Code and Video explains the situation.

```css
input{
    z-index: -1;
    display: none;
}

div{
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
    display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.check{
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.uncheck{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

label:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

input:checked + div label{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

input:checked ~ .check{
    display: block;
}

input:checked ~ .uncheck{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<body = ontouchstart="">
  <input type = "checkbox" id = "clicked">
  <div>
      <label for = "clicked">
          Hello World
      </label>
  </div>

  <span class ="check">Checked!!</span>
  <span class ="uncheck">UnChecked</span>
</body>
```

[Youtube video link](https://youtu.be/A8L8xuD7U_A)

I want the background color of label change into {rgba(0,0,0,0.2)} **only when the mouse hover** or **input tag in front of the label gets clicked**.

It works well as I intended in the computer browser environment.
Like the video, However in the mobile environment,
the background color of the label remains until click the other space of window although input tag already unchecked.

Why does the :checked pseudo-class remain until click the other side in the mobile environment,
and How to solve it? 
(change the label color into transparent as input unchecked without additional click)

**edit updated!!**
Very very thanks of answer by **@Sandesh Sapkota**,
I realized that :hover pseudo-class is the cause of the problem!!
it remains until click another side. 

Media Query is a very good way, but there is a little problem.

If identified the mobile environment by the length of the screen, 
It can't identify in a special situation like the horizontal mode of the wide tablet
**Is there a more obvious way to find out if it's a mobile environment?**

- You can get across better if you visit this post in mobile and run and click the label!
  Thank you for reading and hope you have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is the problem.

```
label:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

change this styling for mobile

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
 label:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
}
}
```

the background is changing in mobile even when it is hovering because the styles of hovering are still applying it even when you uncheck the input. unchecking the input still means hover in mobile.

here is the working demo.

```css
input{
    z-index: -1;
    display: none;
}

div{
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
    display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.check{
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.uncheck{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

label:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
   label:hover{
      background-color: transparent;
  }
}

input:checked + div label{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

input:checked ~ .check{
    display: block;
}

input:checked ~ .uncheck{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<body = ontouchstart="">
  <input type = "checkbox" id = "clicked">
  <div>
      <label for = "clicked">
          Hello World
      </label>
  </div>

  <span class ="check">Checked!!</span>
  <span class ="uncheck">UnChecked</span>
</body>
```

Comment: oh.. thanks for your answer!! so I found that ':hover' state remains after unchecked in the mobile device!!

Comment: But.. Only use media query, It would be unable to in a special situation like tablet device horizontal mode.      
Is there any way to realize that this is a mobile environment other than a media query?
      
Thanks for letting me know What is the cause of the problem!!

Comment: yes. hover state still remains. no, touch device also takes click as hover and there is no such thing as `not hover` for them. this is the way to realize the mobile environment. if you want this to behave the same on other touch devices you need to change the media queries resolution value to like 992px.

Comment: argh.. It sounds very sad ㅠㅠ..
First of all thanks for letting me know what is the problem! 
    
I must explore if there's a good way to resolve with media query and so on, and if it is too hard to find then I must post a new question to find if there's a good way to find mobile environment.
I hope you have a great day

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Sandesh's solution, you could also leverage media `hover` feature:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover

```css
label:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```css
@media (hover: none) {
  label:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```